# to Find filename then find matching string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, find, pattern-matching

Its about to find filename and after that so find some matching string

```
var imgurl = "http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DSC_2355-515x440.test.jpg";
var filename = /.*(?=\.)/.exec(imgurl.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1]);


if( filename.indexOf( "515x" ) !== -1 ) {
   alert("found!")
}



$("body").append(filename);
```

When i use `filename.indexOf( "515x" )` so it doesn't work

But it work when i use `imgurl.indexOf( "515x" )`

What i did wrong ?

Test the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/YkXTs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ4Kn/

This will fit the need `filename.toString().indexOf("515x")` `:)`

**Code**

```
var imgurl = "http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DSC_2355-515x440.test.jpg";
var filename = /.*(?=\.)/.exec(imgurl.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1]);

if(filename.toString().indexOf("515x") != -1) {
   alert("found!")
}



$("body").append(filename);
​
```